# Unable to reference sub class in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin

As you can see below, I can't reference the inner class in my `CustomAdapter` for my app `BindItems`. I'm not sure why it is showing up as red and not found.

```
 class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context,val theList: ArrayList<MyInfo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>(){

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return theList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItems(theList[position])
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.main_row, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
              fun bindItems(user: MyInfo) {
                 val textViewName : TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.row_town_name)
                 val textViewAddress : TextView  = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.row_zip_code)
                 textViewName.text = user.townname
                 textViewAddress.text = user.zipcode
             }
         }       
    }
```

***SOLUTION:***

```
 class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context,val theList: ArrayList<MyInfo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){


        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return theList.size
        }


         override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItems(theList[position])
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.main_row, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(v)
        }

        class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
              fun bindItems(user: MyInfo) {
                 val textViewName : TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.row_town_name)
                 val textViewAddress : TextView  = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.row_zip_code)
                 textViewName.text = user.townname
                 textViewAddress.text = user.zipcode
             }
         }


    }
```

Thanks
-R

Comment: Post code, not images. And thats not a Kotlin issue.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `onBindViewHolder` method like below and also change the name of your `ViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int)
{
}
```

Comment: This yields.... 

Error:(101, 5) Class 'MyCustomAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onBindViewHolder(p0: RecyclerView.ViewHolder!, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: you can't give ViewHolder name ViewHolder as well as

Comment: Provide another name of your viewHolder